# Bottom Tabs active color does not change; focused toggles to false

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I want to style my bottom tabs so that the text color changes, and a bottom border appears when the tab is `focused` so I can determine if it's `active`.  Something is toggling the `focused` callback between true & false:

```js
export default function TabLayout() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        title: '',
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          tabBarLabelStyle: { color: theme.colors.main.dark, fontSize: 12 },
          tabBarLabel: 'Main',
          tabBarIcon: args => {
            console.log('Main args');
            console.log(args);

            return <Feather name="home" size={24} /> />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="search"
        options={{
          tabBarLabelStyle: { color: theme.colors.main.dark, fontSize: 12 },
          tabBarLabel: 'Search',
          tabBarIcon: args => {
            console.log('Search args');
            console.log(args);

            return <Feather name="search" size={24} />;
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

If I am on the `home` tab screen & then click `Search`, this is the console output to match the above `console.log()`'s:

```
 LOG  Home args
 LOG  {"color": "rgb(0, 122, 255)", "focused": true, "size": 25}
 LOG  Home args
 LOG  {"color": "#8E8E8F", "focused": false, "size": 25}
 LOG  Search args
 LOG  {"color": "rgb(0, 122, 255)", "focused": true, "size": 25}
 LOG  Search args
 LOG  {"color": "#8E8E8F", "focused": false, "size": 25}
 LOG  Home args
 LOG  {"color": "rgb(0, 122, 255)", "focused": true, "size": 25}
 LOG  Home args
 LOG  {"color": "#8E8E8F", "focused": false, "size": 25}
 LOG  Search args
 LOG  {"color": "rgb(0, 122, 255)", "focused": true, "size": 25}
 LOG  Search args
 LOG  {"color": "#8E8E8F", "focused": false, "size": 25}
```

I would have expected the `Search args` to have a `focused: true`, which it does, but then get toggled to false.

As you can see, focused is false for all of them.  Why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Your tabbar icon can not change this way you did it. you have provide the constant value so it can't be change.

if you just want to chnage the color of icon and text then use  these attribute:

```
tabBarActiveTintColor, tabBarInactiveTintColor, tabBarActiveBackgroundColor,
```

[Link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaractivebackgroundcolor) to the offical documentation is.

if you want to create a fully customizable bottom tab bar of top tab bar then use this code.

Here is Custom Bottom Tab Screen

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import CAMERABOLD from '../assets/svgs/Camerabold.svg';
import CAMERALINEAR from '../assets/svgs/Cameralinear.svg';
import CONTACTBOLD from '../assets/svgs/contactbold.svg';
import CONTACTLINEAR from '../assets/svgs/contactlinear.svg';
import {colors, fonts} from '../constants/theme';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import PhotosScreen from '../screens/photosScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabBar({state, descriptors, navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
        const label = options.tabBarLabel;
        const icon_name = options.tabBarIcon;
        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const isFocusedStyle = {
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginTop: 1,
          height: 55,

          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        };
        const appcolor1 = isFocused ? colors.primaryColor : '#8B99B1';

        const notFocusedStyle = {
          flex: 1,
          width: Dimensions.get('screen').width / 3,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#ffff',
          height: 56,
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={index}
            accessibilityRole="button"
            onPress={() => onPress()}
            style={isFocused ? isFocusedStyle : notFocusedStyle}>
            {icon_name === 'contacts' ? (
              isFocused ? (
                <CONTACTBOLD width={20} height={20} />
              ) : (
                <CONTACTLINEAR width={20} height={20} />
              )
            ) : icon_name === 'search' ? (
              isFocused ? (
                <Feather name="search" size={20} color={appcolor1} />
              ) : (
                <Feather name="search" size={20} color={appcolor1} />
              )
            ) : isFocused ? (
              <CAMERABOLD width={20} height={20} />
            ) : (
              <CAMERALINEAR width={20} height={20} />
            )}
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 13,
                color: appcolor1,
                fontFamily: fonts.Medium,
              }}>
              {label}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
const BottomTabNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeSreen"
    backBehavior="order"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
    tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Contacts',
        tabBarIcon: 'contacts',
      }}
    />

    <Tab.Screen
      name="SearchScreen"
      component={SearchScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: 'search',
      }}
    />

    <Tab.Screen
      name="PhotosScreen"
      component={PhotosScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Photos',
        tabBarIcon: 'photo-library',
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

Comment: thanks for info.  Unfortunately, using `tabBarActiveTintColor, tabBarInactiveTintColor, tabBarActiveBackgroundColor` doesn't result in any changes.  As you can see in my logs a SINGLE click appears to toggle `focused` from true to false....any ideas?

Comment: you have to applied these in the  <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        title: '',
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    > options.  plus you have to use @react-navigation/bottom-tabs